# How to display resizing adorner in an image inserted in a RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, richeditbox

I'm trying to display resizing adorners to an image inserted in a RichEditBox in a UWP application.

So far I can insert an image using the following code:

```
        private async void InsertImage()
        {
            var picker = new FileOpenPicker { SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary };
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            var files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

            if (files.All(file => file != null))
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                    {
                        var image = new BitmapImage();
                        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                        textEditor.Document.Selection.InsertImage(image.PixelWidth / 2, image.PixelHeight / 2, 0, VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, 
                                                                  file.DisplayName, stream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Once the image is inserted I can resize it, but when I click on the image the cursor doesn't change and the resizing adorners don't display at all, making the resizing task not very user friendly. In other words, what I want is shown in the image below:

[image: resizing adorners]

I initially tried to adapt a solution that I found for WPF in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2035782/8781554), but unfortunately UWP has no concept of adorners. Then, I tried to adapt a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956806/8781554) that I found for Winforms, but that relies on subclassing the RichTextBox control and override its `WndProc` method, and that also is not possible in UWP.

So, how can I acomplish what I described above in UWP?

Comment: This may not solve your issue, but it's worth a look: https://github.com/ysdy44/FanKit.Transformers-Nuget-UWP

Comment: Or, the ImageCropper from the Windows Community Toolkit could be a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/imagecropper

Comment: I found that images with transparency do display the adorners: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76579911/709884. But it's really a pain to deal with, the user experience is frankly quite bad...

Answer (score 1):

> Display resizing adorners to an image inserted in a RichEditBox in a
>   UWP application.

There is no api that can resize the image inserted in the RichEditBox in UWP, you need to customize a control and wrap the image inside it. By dragging the control to resize image. Or programming in wpf or winform and then use [desktop bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-root) to convert it  to UWP app.